# Laravel gives me blank page and 500 error

Tags: laravel, nginx

I'm using nginx+laravel for my project, this project has been developed for months and everything went well before. But now all of a sudden it gives me blank page for all routes and 500 internal server error. Routes like this

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'homepage', 'uses' => 'FrontendPageController@test'));
```

doesn't work at all! However, routes like this

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'homepage', function() {
    return 'hello';
}));
```

works. Has anyone been in this situation before?

Comment: 500 Error - Internal Server Error resembles Error in your code (inside the page your requested) and not in the Route

Comment: I'm setting the debug mode on, but it just doesn't give me any error message...

Comment: Route::get('/','FrontendPageController@test'); Whether this works for you ?

Comment: No it doesn't. Even if in FrontendPageController@test, it's only a 
return 'hello world';

Comment: Have you checked the routes.php whether it has two '/' ?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out where my problem is, I have 2 controllers, one called UserController and the other called OrderController. In my code they mutually depend on each other... The UserController construct function looks like this:

```
class UserController extends BaseController {
    public $orderController;
    public function __construct(OrderController $orderController) {
        $this->orderController = $orderController;
    }
}
```

And the OrderController:

```
class OrderController extends \BaseController {
    public $userController;
    public function __construct(UserController $userController) {
        $this->userController = $userController;
    }
}
```

After I've removed one of the dependency, everything act normal again. I'm just weird that there's no error message/debug info at all...

Comment: Please for all that is Laravel, never depend on controllers within a controller. Certainly never create cyclic dependencies anywhere. Two horrible anti-patterns right there.

Comment: Yeah agreed after spending a whole afternoon debugging this... So would you mind share what would you inject dependencies for this kind of situation? Models maybe?

Comment: Models, no. If you want a shared service across multiple controllers, create a service that contains all your business logic. As another step abstract the models away by putting a repository in between the service and the DAL

Comment: I want to invoke function in one controller from another controller, let's say in UserController, I want to invoke ImageController->getAvatarImageInfo() to get the user's avatar image information, or maybe invoke PaymentController->makePayment() in OrderController when creating a new order... so you're saying it's better to put all these kinds of functions in a service? Like a service provider in Laravel?

Comment: No the service provider would register the services. You put your logic in separate classes that can be injected into the controllers. You're thinking correctly, that you want to reuse code but implementing it wrong. Make an image service for example that has the functionality for images. Then inject that into both controllers and use it as such.

Comment: Ok, I get the point, thanks! It's quite helpful to stop coding to think about design pattern every once a while. Again, thanks pal!